# Can Css Selector be used to write customized path using tag name traversing?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css

I wrote a xpath for the following using tag name traversing 
[image: login button]

This is the xpath I wrote -

```
.//form[@class = 'form-horizontal']/div[3]/div/input
```

and it works fine but when I tried to write this in for CssSelector then its not working

```
form[class = 'form-horizontal']/div[3]/div/input
```

Am I doing correct? or traversing is not possible in CssSelector ?

Answer (score 1):

```
form.form-horizontal > div:nth-child(3) > div > input
```

I suggest spending 20 minutes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)